# How can I rewrite this select statement for guaranteed 100% test coverage?

Tags: testing, go, code-coverage, channel

This is driving me OCD-crazy.  Suppose I have the following function:

```
func Map(quit <-chan struct{}, dst chan<- interface{}, src <-chan interface{}, f func(interface{}) interface{} {
    for {
        select {
        case v, ok := <- src:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            select {
            case dst <- f(v):
            case <-quit:
                return
            }
        case <-quit:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

It sends f(v) on dst for each value v received from src until either src or quit is closed and empty or a value is received from quit.

Now, suppose I want to write a test which demonstrates that it can be cancelled:

```
func TestMapCancel(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    quit := make(chan struct{})
    success := make(chan struct{})
    wg.Add(3)

    src := // channel providing arbitrary values until quit is closed
    dst := make(chan interface{})

    // mapper
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer close(dst)
        Map(quit, dst, src, double)
    }()

    // provide a sink to consume values from dst until quit is closed
    timeout(quit, 10*time.Millisecond)
    wait(success, &wg)

    select {
    case <-success:
    case <-time.After(100 * time.Millisecond):
        t.Error("cancellation timed out")
    }
}
```

The undefined functions here aren't terribly important.  Please assume they work.  `timeout` closes its channel parameter after the specified amount of time, and `wait` closes its channel parameter after `wg.Wait()`.

The problem is that this won't offer 100% coverage because a select case is chosen uniformly at (pseudo-)random if both are ready to send/receive.  The following version of `Map` doesn't have this problem, but suffers from potential indefinite blocking if the upstream channel (src) isn't closed:

```
func Map(quit <-chan struct{}, dst chan<- interface{}, src <-chan interface{}, f func(interface{}) interface{}) {
    for v := range src {
        select {
        case dst <- f(v):
        case <-quit:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I can sort-of solve this by rewriting the test to repeat several times in a loop, so that each branch has a chance to be chosen at random.  I've tried as few as 10 iterations and reached 100% coverage with all tests passing (there are other tests besides this one).  But it bugs the crap out of me that I can't seem to write a best-of-both-worlds version that won't block if the upstream channel isn't closed and is guaranteed to give 100% test coverage (not just likely).

Any inspiration for me?

P.S., if you're curious why "doesn't block if upstream channel isn't closed" is important, it's just another bit of OCD.  This function is exported, meaning that if client code is misbehaving, my code misbehaves.  I'd like it to be more resilient than that, which the first version is.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I heavily edited this answer because it was still incorrect.  This seems to work quite well.

Okay, so I'm feeling pretty sheepish.  I must've been burned out when I was looking at this.  It's absolutely possible to traverse those select statements in a deterministic fashion:

```
func TestMapCancel(t *testing.T) {
    src := make(chan interface{})
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        Map(quit, nil, src, double)
    }()

    close(quit)

    select {
    case <-done:
    case <-time.After(100 * time.Millisecond):
        t.Error("quitting pre-send failed")
    }

    src = make(chan interface{})
    quit = make(chan struct{})
    done = make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        Map(quit, nil, src, double)
    }()

    src <- 1
    close(quit)

    select {
    case <-done:
    case <-time.After(100 * time.Millisecond):
        t.Error("quitting pre-send failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd split it up into multiple test functions.  Also, there's two more exit cases that you're not testing: receiving from `src` then sending on `dst` _then_ closing `quit`, and exiting because `src` was closed.  https://play.golang.org/p/KI9OJLsHdc

Comment: Those are already handled in other test functions.  Just this particular one was giving me fits because I hadn't realized I could traverse the select statement deterministically by setting channels to nil so they would never receive.

Comment: Don't even need to set them to nil, to be honest.  Simply making them unbuffered channels that you don't call a receive on is mechanically identically to the channel being nil.  Your test wouldn't change at all if you created a unbuffered `dst` channel and handed it to `Map`, and just never bothered to do a `<-dst`.

Comment: Well, before this version, I was sinking on the dst channel ( in the select stmt below it).  That was a problem as well.  The addition of the done channel is really what did it, I guess.