# How to unit test async events in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I have some `Go` code which uses a `Ticker` to send a periodic signal. It's handled by a `select` block (code below)
But my unit test coverage report in VSCode is telling me that the block is untested.

My question is, what is the best practice technique for unit testing such code? As I understand it, the normal pattern is to use a mock interface for the function under test.
So would I have to pass in a mock `Ticker` object to this function? The real `Ticker` has an embedded channel, which is used to send the periodic events.
All the examples I've looked at are really simple and just involve creating a mock interface, with direct function calls. I've not seen an example which tests async events.

I'm coming from a Java background, which has really good mocking frameworks. Is there anything available for Go, or do people generally roll their own mocks for testing?

Any links to web resources, or example code to demonstrate how to construct a unit test for this appreciated.

```
func SignalProcess(process string, interval int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
  
  ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(interval) * time.Hour)
  done := make(chan bool)

  defer func() {
    wg.Done()
    done <- true
  }()

  for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        zlog.Info().Msg("Done event received")
        return nil
    case <-ticker.C:
        zlog.Info().Msg("Ticker event received")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/38775223/10197418

Comment: I would say the best is to rewrite your code in a way you could [mock the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48173756/720999) and then write a test function in a way so that both cases in the `select` statement are exercised. Also note that 100% test coverage in most cases is not a "silver bullet" in itself: a test must test some sensible set of conditions, not just make sure every code path is _somehow_ executed.

Comment: @kostix agreed, but Sonarqube wants at least 80% coverage. Also feels wrong to require that code must change structure to allow testing. However if this is the general mindset for Go coding, then I'll have to 'Go' with it :)

Comment: Well, I would not say Go requires anything in this case; that's just a general observation: if you have a piece of code which relies on measuring time intervals to function, you have to write your tests in a way they exercise the subsystem under test in a way it really sees such time intervals passing. Now you either have to either actually use the system's time for that (basically, execute `time.Sleep()` in tests) or "mock (virtualize) the time" to fully control its flow, but…

Comment: ….Tests which use real system time are well-known to be fragile as neither Go runtime nor the programs written in it, nor the operating systems Go programs typically run on do not provide hard real-time guarantees (and most of the time even no soft real-time guarantees can be provided). It means the tests which do `time.Sleep` may work OK on your laptop and then fail when run on CI because at that moment of time it had to run multiple heavy jobs concurrenty and your call to `time.Sleep(N)` had happened to sleep like `3×N` or whatever. Hence such tests cannot be considered to be _definite…_

Comment: …and so you cannot even sensibly make such tests fail your test suite—they can only be made report errors at best. With virtualized time, tests behave fully predictably. Of course, there exist another approach: do not test subsystems which rely on measuring time, and instead test _parts_ of them which do not rely on time passing. That's doable but it's obviously no substitute for end-to-end testing of at least some subsystems.